# ASIHTTPRequest Issue With NSNotificationCenter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, asihttprequest, nsnotificationcenter

I download Images Using `ASIHTTPRequest`. I wrote This Code:

```
+(void)GetImagesURL
{
    NSLog(@"%i",[TripsArray count]);
    for (int i=0;i< [TripsArray count]; i++) 
    {

        NSURL *DetailTripURL = [NSURL URLWithString:[[TripsArray objectAtIndex:i] TripURL]];
        __block ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:DetailTripURL];
        [request setCompletionBlock:^{
            NSData *TripHTMLData = [request responseData];
            NSLog(@"url :  %@",DetailTripURL);
            [[TripsArray objectAtIndex:i] setTripData:TripHTMLData];
            //NSLog(@"%@",DetailTripHTMLData);
            // 2
            TFHpple *DetailTripParser = [TFHpple hppleWithHTMLData:TripHTMLData];

            // Get Image
            NSString *ImageTripXpathQueryString = @"//div[@class='image_container']/img";
            NSArray *ImageTripNodes = [DetailTripParser searchWithXPathQuery:ImageTripXpathQueryString];
            NSLog(@"%i",[ImageTripNodes count]);
            for (int j=0 ;j<[ImageTripNodes count]; j++)
            {
                [[TripsArray objectAtIndex:i] setImageUrl:[[ImageTripNodes objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"src"]];
                NSLog(@"%@",[[ImageTripNodes objectAtIndex:j] objectForKey:@"src"]);
            }


        }];
        [request setFailedBlock:^{
            NSError *error = [request error];
            NSLog(@"Get Image URL Failed %@", error.localizedDescription);
        }];

        [request startAsynchronous];        
    }
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"Get Images URL Success" object:self];
}
```

i want `postNotificationName` To Call Another Function .

The Problem is `NSNotificationCenter`, not `postNotificationName` . 
Any Help Please ?

Comment: Please write something about where you think your error lies, what your code is supposed to do and any other relevant info

Comment: i have Trips Array  with Images URL I wanna Get Image URL By Parsing HTML Page Using TFHpple In Asynchronous Way and i wanna if i get All Images Download PostNotificationCenter

Comment: Is there an object that has added itself as an NSNotificationCenter observer for notifications named `"Get Images URL Success"`?

Comment: no Object Added It Self Craig

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to add an observer `Get_Images_URL_Success`

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(gotMessages:) name:Get_Images_URL_Success object:nil];
```

When you `postNotificationName` in `+GetImagesURL` method, this will be called

```
- (void)gotMessages:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"This will be called after the postNotificationName");
}
```

it is recommended you `removeObserver` when not needed (for example, in `dealloc`)

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:Get_Images_URL_Success object:nil];
```

Now when you `postNotificationName` like this, `gotMessages` method should be called

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:Get_Images_URL_Success object:self];
```

[super easy, isn't it?]

Comment: This What I do Warif But Not Call GotMessage ?

Comment: You are posting a notification Get_Images_URL_Success. and gotMessages will fire every time you post notification with Get_Images_URL_Success.

Comment: can i Call GotMessages With Argument Int ?

Comment: yes. But you need to use NSNumber instead of integer. You can use string directly.

Comment: please can you write how can i call method with argument type NSNumber ?